# How to change a button's shape using xml or using java?

Tags: android, user-interface

I want to make a custom button with shape, how to do this?

Comment: "want make custom button with shape" is not a understandable description .Elaborate the problem.

Comment: See this: [custom button style and theme in android](http://blog.androgames.net/40/custom-button-style-and-theme/)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is the sample button which is of **oval** shape.. The `gradient` says the start n end color along with the angle. corners for the oval shape..Try this.. Mention the name of this **xml** in button background `android:background="@drawable/sample"`.Save the xml in **drawable**.

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:startColor="#302226"
        android:endColor="#6D7B8D"
        android:angle="45"/>
    <padding android:left="6dp"
        android:top="6dp"
        android:right="6dp"
        android:bottom="6dp" />
    <corners android:radius="30dp" />

</shape>
```

Also check this [link](http://blog.androgames.net/40/custom-button-style-and-theme/) for custom button.

Comment: @suresh what if I want it to look like an arrow ? is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Another way to find button in different shapes

Use imagebutton in xml as

```
      <ImageButton
             android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:src="@drawable/shape_oval" />
```

**Shape_oval** is an image which we can take from google serching or drawing ourself in paint or photoshop.